# Get aria-expanded value Angular 2/4/5 for ngb-accordion

Tags: angular, angular5, accordion, wai-aria

**UPDATE**

Changed the file to scss. Found a fix.

```
/deep/ .my-accordion .card-header a[aria-expanded="true"] {
img.icon{
    filter:invert(0%);
}}

/deep/.my-accordion .card-header a[aria-expanded="false"] {
img.icon{
    filter:invert(40%);
}}
```

Previous post

I would like to retrieve **aria-expanded** value (e.g. true or false) of ngb-accordion so that I can manipulate it on my component side. I've placed an icon beside each panel title. If the aria-expanded value is true, I want it to be white in colour, otherwise grey. Could someone help me?

Here is my accordion code: (.html)

```
<ngb-accordion *ngFor="let pages of getColumndataForm(FaultForm); let i=index" #acc="ngbAccordion"  [attr.aria-expanded]="selected" [activeIds]="activeIds" formArrayName="functions">
```

And here is my code for the icon: (.html)

```
    <img class="icon" [ngStyle]="{'filter': 'invert' + selected ? '(0%)' : '(40%)'}" *ngSwitchCase="0" src="assets/icons/connector.png">
```

I've tried the following css method but it didn't work either (.css)

```
a[aria-expanded="true"]{
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: Your CSS rule is for links (`a`). Your aria-expanded attribute is on a `ngb-accordion`. And your expression inside ngStyle lacks parentheses: `'invert' + (selected ? '(0%)' : '(40%)')`

Comment: Sorry I edited accordingly, didn't seem to work. Any other workarounds? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In general, ARIA attributes can be treated like any other attributes and be used in CSS selectors.  Your selector code looks ok.  Have you viewed the generated html to make sure you need a selector on the anchor tag?  I would recommend bringing up the code inspector and manually changing the styles for the elements you want to change and visually making sure the style change actually works.  Then work backwards from there and have your CSS selector use the same values you tried in the inspector.

Comment: hi slugolicious, thanks for helping! I managed to find a fix